# curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: REFUSED_STREAM (err 7)

Tags: libcurl, gitlab

Estou tentando registrar um runner do Gitlab, mas quando rodo o comando de registro especificado na API, ocorre erro. O comando que eu tento executar é como o descrito na API:

```
curl --request POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/runners" --form "token=ipzXrMhuyyJPifUt6ANz" --form "description=test-1-20150125-test" --form "tag_list=ruby,mysql,tag1,tag2"
```

O erro obtido é:

```
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: REFUSED_STREAM (err 7)
```

Referências: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a API do Gitlab estava configurada para desabilitar o uso do verbo POST. Por isso as chamadas get funcionavam mas essa chamada em particular não estava funcionando. Descobri o problema da seguinte forma:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS <url> --form token=<o token>
```

Os verbos retornados foram:

```
allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD
```